# NSPredicate based on whether this object is related to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

First off, thank you for reading.

I'm trying to build an NSPredicate for the following scenario.

Object A can have 0, 1, or many Object Bs.
Object B has an inverse relationship with object B.

I'm trying to perform a fetch for all of the Bs that are NOT in A.  This seems like it should be straight forward, but since it is a search based on the objects themselves (and not an attribute of the objects, except perhaps their primary key), I'm not sure how to procede.  Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

An NSFetchRequest for all B objects w/ the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b.objectA != %@", objectA];
```